# Implementing Phone Calling feature in an app for android and iOS.Using Phonegap

Tags: android, ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am a beginner and I want to implement Phone Calling feature in an app for android and iOS. Using Phonegap ,Is it feasible in case of tablet formfactors also like iPad or Nexus 7 etc? From my understanding, Tablets do not support calling feature otherwise. Can some one provide an idea if we can leverage Phonegap plugins, if there is any such option there. Plus, please provide some insights on integrating Phone-cellular/wifi calling? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try the code from this link http://rickluna.com/wp/2012/02/making-a-phone-call-from-within-phonegap-in-android-and-ios/

It will initiate a call in phonegap which will support for both IOS and Android.

Comment: Link is helpful.Thank you very much.  But can you suggest if this will work incase of tablet formfactor? Major thing i would want to understand is if Phonegap can help make Phone calls from iPads/ android tabs also which is otherwise not supported?

Comment: @Neeti:I think it will works with above links.you try that one and check with yours.

If my answer is helpful then mark it as accept.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this function to open the mobile's dialled (both `Android` and `iOS`) and pass a mobile number as a parameter:

```
function callingFunction(mobile_number) {
    window.location.href = "tel:" + mobile_number;
}
```